# How to remove <ul> unordered list's last <li> list item's border using CSS without changing anything in HTML code?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

How can I remove a `<ul>` unordered list's last `<li>` list item's border using CSS without adding any class to the last list item?

See live example here: http://jsbin.com/umose

```css
body { background-color: #fff; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; }
li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0 20px 0 20px;
    border-right:1px solid green;
}
#navlist li:last-child { border-right: ; }
```

```html
<p id="hello"></p>
<ul id="navlist" >
  <li ><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
  <li id="active"><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Add this style and you don't need to modify anything else:

```
#navlist li:last-child { border-right:0px; }
```

Edit:

### Original Script

Original script to which the answer applies is posted here because jsbin.com may delete content not viewed for 3 months.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
<head>
<title>Sandbox</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
body { background-color: #fff; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; }
#navlist li
{
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
padding:0 20px 0 20px;border-right:1px solid red;
}
/* !!!!!!!!!!!!!! PASTE ANSWER HERE TO MAKE THE FIX !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! */
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Hello from JS Bin</p>
  <p id="hello"></p>
  <ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There may be compatibility problems, see http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Comment: Ouch, IE6 ... if it doesn't support the same level of CSS standards, you might have to switch to a different solution like adding a class to the last list item even though you didn't want to do that. Does anybody else have an IE6 solution that's in line with the original question?

Comment: Why not use this answer to formulate a brand new SO question based on IE6 and CSS (put IE6 in the title of the new question) - you will get more specific answers and it shouldn't be considered a duplicate.

Answer (score 10):

I do this all the time without CSS3 or JavaScript. All you need to do is float your `li` and use an advanced selector `+`:

```
<style>
ul li {
 float: left;
 border: none; }

li + li {
 border-left: 1px solid #F00; } 
</style>
```

This will keep the first `li` from having a border.

Comment: nice. never thought about doing it this way.

Comment: The `+` is also known as the *adjacent sibling* selector.

Answer (score 3):

Using CSS3

To remove the last `<li>` in a `<ul>`

```
ul li:last-child { 
    border:none; 
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

I would use CSS to do everything, but in this case using `:last-child` is not compatible between browsers (I have only encountered IE problems).

I don't hesitate to use JavaScript to help me style, but only where CSS can't do the trick on all browsers.

I see two ways to do this, the first recommend adding a class to every last `<li>` inside a `<ul>` list.
This can be done server side, but I'm not an expert on server side coding, so if you use jQuery you can write this simple code:

```
$("ul li:last-child").addClass("noborder");
```

This will add the class `noborder` to every last item inside a `ul`. jQuery uses a JavaScript CSS selector engine so that you can use more complex selectors and get them to work on all browsers. You should read about the stand alone engine [Sizzle](http://sizzlejs.com/) if you are interested.

You could also add an inline style to every last item, but I recommend using the code above if it works.

Using `$.css()` you can add style directly to the item;

```
$("ul li:last-child").css("border-right", "0");
```

It uses the same selector to find the items.

If you don't like using jQuery it is possible to write a pure JavaScript code to get the same effect, but why bother?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first-child` because the `last-child` property comes in CSS3.

```
#navlist li:first-child { border-left:0; }
```

Check below the link:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Now check below the code:

```css
body { background-color: #fff; font: 16px Helvetica, Arial; color: #000; }
#navlist li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding:0 20px 0 20px;border-left:1px solid red
}
#navlist li:first-child{border-left:none}
```

```html
<p>Hello from JS Bin</p>
<p id="hello"></p>
<ul id="navlist">
  <li id="active"><a href="#" id="current">Item one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item two</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Item five</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: My question is for last child

Comment: @JitendraVyas -  yes I know but last-child is not support lower version ie bcz that is css3 property. So i have some trick. just my suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I would try jQuery, something like this:

```
$("#myDiv ul li:last-child").addClass("lastLi");
```

You would need to make the `lastLi` class set the `li` border width to 0.

Here is a link to the jQuery `last-child` selector documentation: http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lastChild

Comment: i wanted to know is there any pure css way

Answer (score 0):

Use like this

```
li:nth-child(){ border-left:none;}
```

**Note**

Put the `li` position number (like 3 or 4 or 5) inside `()`; also manipulate border left or right.

```css
div p { display:inline-block; background:darksalmon; padding:4px;
        border-left:13px solid silver; }
div p:first-of-type { color:#fff; border-left:13px solid magenta; }

li { border-right:2px solid blue; 
     display:inline-block;padding:7px; background:skyblue;color:#fff;
}
ul li:nth-last-of-type(2) + li {
    background:hsla(80,100%,60%,0.16);
    border-right:none;
    color:#000000;
}
```

```html
<h1>both universal solid style for 
   <i style='color:#1AB9FC'>Left or Right</i> border remove
</h1>
<div>
  <h3 style="color:olive; text-align:center;">Target rightborder</h3>
  <p>The first paragraph.</p>
  <p>The second paragraph.</p>
  <p>The third paragraph.</p>
  <p>The fourth paragraph.</p>
</div>
<br>
<ul>
  <li>li-1</li>
  <li>li-2</li>
  <li>li-3</li>
  <li>li-4</li>
  <li>li-5</li>
  <li>li-6</li>
</ul>
<h3>Remove left border</h3>
<p><b>Note: </b><span>Last <code>li</code> always selected if you increase the <code>li</code> items in future</span></p>
```